# Drawing a graph in Java JPEG/PNG for a simple map

Tags: java, maps, android-studio

For my game i need to create a map based on a graph starting from the coordinates of the nodes, using "roads" instead of simple lines (for the edges) and circles instead of points (for nodes), but i don't now exactly which library to use.

As far as I now the standard graph visualization libraries wouldn't make me create this kind of graph.

Here is a quick example of what i mean:

[image]

If possible for the points i would like to use a custom textures

I only need to learn how to create the picture, because i know how to handle it in my game

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i want a good way to create a map for my app using my graph as a reference

Comment: @DeNasti just iterate your nodes and place them on a plane?

Comment: Try editing your question to include example images of the kind of visual you want (since there are many, many kinds of map we might derive from a graph), lay out what you know how to do so far, and go into detail about the particular step in the process you're stuck on and need help with. A complete end-to-end solution probably won't fit in an answer, so the more specific you can be in you (first) question, the better your chances of getting a quality answer. You can always ask a separate question in a new post for the next step you need help with.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "aesthetically pleasing"? Different games have very different aesthetical styles. Do you have a concept art or a mockup or something?

Comment: @philipp i mean that it doesent seem a simple graph like this  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/Frucht_graph_3COL.svg/220px-Frucht_graph_3COL.svg.png

Comment: @DMGregory i hope now is a bit better

Comment: You followed the first part of my comment. Now for the rest. You haven't yet told us which steps in this process you know how to do, or which specific step you want help with. There's a lot in here - laying out your graph into a set of 2D coordinates, loading and displaying images on the screen, positioning images on your node coordinates, drawing lines or stretched ribbons along the edges. It's also unclear whether you just want to compose this view on the screen, or "bake" it into a texture/render target to use as a literal background image.

Comment: Sorry for being so inconsistent in my edits.
I want to create like a jpeg-png file to use as background for the game.
In short, the image is a map and has painted on roads (even straight, i don't care that the seems "realistic"),
So i want to know what kind of libraries can i use to create it having the coordinates of the nodes and link them with "thick lines"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is just very vague and lacks any details. I think you question should be, what graphics library you should use.

I'm not working with Java but maybe you look for something like [lwjgl](https://www.lwjgl.org/), which is one of many possible graphics libraries you can use. Second there are many tutorials on how to use it. If you want to keep your Nodes any dynamic, don't just create a static png for that.

Now, if you use one of those libraries, you will likely create those nodes and paths as entities. With positions, orientation and a graphical representation. The nodes will have an array of paths, so in game you can move a unit from one node to another via a path.

There is just not more to say, since your request is so vague.

Comment: Questions requesting library / technology recommendations are off topic; please don't recommend changes that would result in closing the question.